# Assign result of command in a variable

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu, grep

I got this strange result today while assigning result of a command in a variable.

This command:

```
git branch | grep 480
```

gives me result like this:

```
branch_name_480
```

given that `branch_name_480` is the only branch with 480 in it.

But when I try to do this:

```
temp=`git branch | grep 480`
```

Or this:

```
temp=$(git branch | grep 480)
```

and after that: `echo $temp`
this doesn't give me the expected result - which should be the same as before. Instead, this gives me result like `all my directory listing and the expected result` in a single line.

I know I can do this to get the expected result:

```
temp=$(echo 'git branch | grep 480')
```

So, my question is why is this happening? Why am I not getting the expected result before?

Comment: this is indeed strange; are you using the same variable `temp` at another place in you script?

Comment: do you get those results on the command line? What do you get if you just do these two commands on command line: `temp=$(git branch | grep 480)`and `echo $temp` ?

Comment: this is the only code I'm executing. no code before or after. just assign and echo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `echo "$temp"`.

The output from `git branch` includes an asterisk, which the shell expands to the directory listing. Quoting will prevent it from doing that.